# Search in multiple array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I want to Search a value in an array Like

```
`[_id] => MongoId Object (
[$id] => 511f4ce622efc34f15000001
)
[metadata] => Array (
[filename] => 6410-funny_face.gif
[parrent] => myfolder/newfolder2
[user] => Array ( >>>>>>>> i need to fetch all users
    [root] => 7  
    [admin] => 7
    [user] => 0
)
[group] => Array (
    [23] => 2
)
)
[filename] => 6410-funny_face.gif
[uploadDate] => MongoDate Object (
[sec] => 1361005798
[usec] => 799000
)
[length] => 3083
[chunkSize] => 262144
[md5] => eb3846f78f461165e5bf59a05707edd1`
```

I need to find the user's key and value in PHP or MongoShell
 im using `db.collection.find(array(metadata.filename: 6410-funny_face.gif));` gives the correct answer but while in finding  `db.collection.find(array(metadata.user: array(7)));`

Comment: can you be a bit more clear. Its really unreadable what you exactly want.

Comment: need to extract the users from this collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"metadata.user.root":7})
```

This should work if I understand your question.

Comment: but how to do it when `root` is not Known